# How to get git diff with full context using gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to get the changes to a file in a git repository using the gitpython library. 
I'm using
`repo.git.diff(commit_a, commit_b, file_path)`
 for that. But I need to increase the context of the diff similar to the `-U` argument. How can I do this using the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `subprocess` at the end, like this:
`subprocess.check_output(['git', 'diff', '-U500', commit_a, commit_b, file_path], cwd=project_dir)`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, `repo.git.diff(commit_a, commit_b, file_path, unified=1000)`

See git-diff Manual

> -U
> --unified=<n>
> Generate diffs with  lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies --patch.